# Обьясните, почему при запуске PyQt5 в консоли пишет: QApplication: invalid style override passed, ignoring it

Tags: qt, pyqt5

Когда я запускаю программу она у меня работает, но пишет это :

> QApplication: invalid style override passed, ignoring it.

Сам код:

https://gist.github.com/zhenyamega/448a05036478acd768a5e476bf562418

```
!/usr/bin/python3.5
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets,QtCore
import sys
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
class Win(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self,title='',x=300,y=70):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self,None)
        self.setWindowTitle(title)
        self.resize(x,y)
        self.label = []
        self.button = []
    def set_label(self, text=''):
        lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel(text)
        self.label.append(labell)
    def set_button(self, text='', click=None):
        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(text)
        btn.clicked.connect(click)
        self.button.append(btn)
    def run(self):
        mesto = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        for i in self.label:
            addWidget(i)
        for i in self.button:
            addWidget(i)
        self.setLayout(mesto)
        self.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

qt = Win(title='первая программа')
qt.run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваше окружение линукс с GTK3 или что-то еще экзотичное? Qt ругается на стиль темы, полученной от окружения. Можно попробовать вызвать статический метод ДО создания QApplication (они определены как classmethod в PyQt?)

`QApplication.setDesktopSettingsAware(False)`

В С++ можно было выдать каков стиль задается программе на отладку, но я не знаю как это записать на питоне.

`qDebug() << QApplication::style()->metaObject()->className();`

Comment: Он всё равно ругается если перед ним написать эту команду.Но спасибо что обьяснил. Да у меня линукс с gtk3.

Comment: @Евгений Каратаев попробуй запустить с параметром -style Fusion. QStyleFactory.keys() дает список доступныx стилей. Это проблема связана с тем что нет плагина под GTK3. Выход может быть в апгрейде до Qt версии 5.8, там было добавлено. Если это уже она, надо проверить наличие плагина libqgtk3 и его зависимостей. Возможно, плагин можно портировать в старую версию "если очень нужно", такое случается

Comment: написал строчку: print(QtWidgets.QStyleFactory.keys())
выдал: ['Windows', 'Fusion'] . И да у меня qt5.8

Comment: ух, прогуглил форумы, похоже сейчас это какая-то повальная  проблема, по крайней мере если желательно "единое" оформление приложения, схоже с GTK. Можно пробовать сменить стиль с помощью qt5ct, или задать стиль в параметрах запуска. Сам я с этим не сталкивался, использую только переопределенные виджеты.